# Which site is suitable for asking questions regarding the Kindle platform?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there any suitable place where I can ask question like why my Kindle is not charging, etc? I have a question regarding the Kindle, but can't guess the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

We have a site in the network dedicated to ebooks, [Ebooks Stack Exchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/). [Kindle](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kindle) even is their most popular tag. Their [Help Center](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says you can ask questions like

> My [ereader or electronic device] isn't working because [specific problem]; how can I fix it?

which seems to fit your problem.

Comment: So question like Why my kindle is not charging are accepted in Ebooks Stack Exchange? Plus shouldn't it be a website like where one can ask question about e books of kindle and not about working of kindle?

Comment: @JitendraSingh It's still your best shot; their Help Center seems to indicate such a question can be asked there (with more details, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Glorfindel's answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2643/44325), *Android-based* Kindle devices are also on-topic on Android.SE.

We have some tags related to Kindle devices:

- [amazon-kindle](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle)
- [amazon-kindle-fire](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire)
- [amazon-kindle-fire-hd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire-hd)

---

My personal observation regarding [Ebooks Stack Exchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/), while there was a discussion about [Should Kindle Fire questions not about reading ebooks be off-topic?](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/147/4517) with the answer, "yes, they are off-topic", [recent questions unrelated to e-books per-se](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bkindle%5d%20closed%3a0%20answers%3a1%20-reader%20-readers%20-book%20-books%20-textbook%20-textbooks%20-ebook%20-ebooks%20-epub%20-page%20-pages%20-app%20-apps%20-pdf%20-read%20-rent) seem to be left opened and answered.